# Get only numbers from tag using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input xml

```
&lt;citation&gt;[&lt;xref linkend="XEx31"/&gt;1,&amp;#x000A0;&lt;xref
linkend="XEx32"/&gt;2]&lt;/citation&gt;
```

output xml

```
&lt;out&gt;1,2&lt;/out&gt;
```

Can anyone help me to get this output using xslt 2.0? I want to get only numbers and comma. Entities and brackets will not come.

Comment: What kind of numbers, only positive integers like `1` or `2`? Or more complex formats?

Comment: yes martin. only positive integers. if comma following with numbers, that also i want in output xml

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:template match="citation"><out><xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^,0-9]+', '')"/></out></xsl:template>`.